# Using pgf to print raw numbers without math delimiters

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, libertine

I'm trying to have `pgf` output a number in raw format, but I don't know how to do it so any help would be greatly appreciated. If you look below, the problem is that `\roundednumber` expands to `$1,000$`, and I would like to have it expanded to `1,000` instead. I have tried using the `xstring` package with no luck.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfmathparse{1e9}\pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/1e6}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
\pgfmathprintnumberto{\pgfmathresult}{\roundednumber}
\roundednumber \ 1,000
% \pgfmathparse{\roundednumber}
% \pgfmathparse{\StrBetween{\roundednumber}{$}{$}}
% \pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

PS: if you know of a better way to have numbers printed using the Libertine font, please let me know.

Comment: `\pgfmathprintnumberto[assume math mode=true]{\pgfmathresult}{\roundednumber}`

Comment: Does the solution have to use pgf-based expressions, or would a "straight-lua" solution be acceptable? While you're at it, it's not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve: What's a "raw" format for a number?

Comment: I just want to escape math mode. @egreg solution is what I needed, but if you have another solution using `lua`, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
\pgfmathprintnumberto[assume math mode=true]{\pgfmathresult}{\roundednumber}
```

that will avoid entering math mode.

An easier way is using `expl3` and `siunitx`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

%% if you really want a comma for separating groups
\sisetup{group-separator={,},group-four-digits=true}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printnumber}{m}
 {
  \num{ \fp_to_decimal:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printnumber{1e9/1e6}

\end{document}
```