# Pretty print math in tikz/pgf figure labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3

I have `tikz/pgfplots` figures with math labels I would like to be able to reproduce with different values. I'm defining values with code like `\def\a{1}` at the top of the document, so I can easily reproduce the figure by changing the hard-coded values, e.g. `\def\a{2}`. The calculations involved are simple, but they do involve taking inverses and multiplying by $1$, which I would like to see simplify nicely in the printed labels. Is there a simple way to achieve (at least) the following?

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,calc}% I use these packages already

\def\a{0.5}
\def\ia{2}% inverse of a

\def\b{1}

\begin{document}

Default:
\begin{align*}
1/\a x + \b y
\end{align*}


Desired:
\begin{align*}
\ia x + y
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a dedicated package? Maybe `latex3` syntax can help? I'm already using `tikz/pgfplots/calc`.

**Edit:** Follow-up on Peter's answer. A simple way to change `1x` to `x` is, for instance, to condition on the presence of `1` with the `ifthen` package:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\FormatNumber}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}
    {}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{#1}%
       \pgfmathprintnumber{\temp}}}%
```

Comment: A possibly related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180945/using-pgf-to-print-raw-numbers-without-math-delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `\pgfmathprintnumber` (along with `/pgf/number format/frac`) to format the number.

[image]

#### Future Enhancements:

- One woulc provide a starred variant that suppresses a `1` so that `1x` woulbe be printed as `x`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac}

\newcommand{\FormatNumber}[1]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{#1}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\temp}%
}

\def\a{0.5}
\def\b{0.3333333333333}
  
\begin{document}

Default:  $1/\a x + \b y$

Using \verb|\pgfmathprintnumber|:
$\FormatNumber{1/\a} x + \FormatNumber{\b} y$

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's fantastic. Is the star variant available or is that for a future enhancement of the package? (to print `1x` as `x`)

Comment: Okay, got it! Here `\newcommand{\FormatNumberTwo}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}
    {}{\pgfmathsetmacro{\temp}{#1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\temp}}}%`

Comment: here's one that handles ones and zeros: `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}\OR\equal{#1}{0}\OR\equal{#1}{-0}}`. It converts expressions like `-0+x` to `+x`, which is much better. The next step would be to conditionally remove the plus sign as well and convert `0x` to an empty string.

Comment: @PatrickT: The supresion of a `1` was left as a future enhancement. I personally would not do that by default as the removal is only appropriate for the case where the number if followed by a variable.  Thus, was proposing a `\FormatNumber*` which would suppress the 1, but used as `\FormatNumber{}` it would not (or vice versa depending on your preference).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks Peter!

Answer (score 3):

This problem can be solved with the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) package which give you access to an open source CAS, called [SAGE](https://www.sagemath.org/) and the Python programming language. The Python allows you to make the printing look as you desire. There were 3 cases I saw: `if a.denominator() == 1:` checks if the number is an integer so it can be typeset a particular way. Case 2a  is `if a.numerator()==1:` to check whether the fraction has a numerator of 1 (we don't want 1/4 to print as 4/1) and Case 2b is when the input is a fraction where the numerator is not 1. In this case we want to typeset the number as a fraction in LaTeX so it looks nicer.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,sagetex}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,calc}% I use these packages already
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
def prettyprint(a,b):
    if a.denominator() == 1:
        output = r"\begin{align*}"
        output += r"%s x+%s y"%(a,b)
        output += r"\end{align*}"
    else:
        if a.numerator()==1:
            output = r"\begin{align*}"
            output += r"%s x+%s y"%(a.denominator(),b)
            output += r"\end{align*}"
        else:
            output = r"\begin{align*}"
            output += r"\frac{%s}{%s} x+%s y"%(a.denominator(),a.numerator(),b)
            output += r"\end{align*}"

    return output
a = 1/2
b = 1
result = prettyprint(a,b)
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{result}
\end{document}
```

The output running in [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is below:
[image]

I made a simplifying assumption that the input was in the form of a fraction. You could do programming convert decimal numbers to fractions if you don't mind additional complexities. SAGE commands for rational numbers are [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_standard/sage/rings/rational.html_). If you're not familiar with Python, it's an extra headache but learning it is easier and you'll find the `sagetex` package is extremely important for any mathematical work.

SAGE is not part of a LaTeX distribution so it needs to either be downloaded onto your computer or accessed through a free Cocalc account.

Comment: Very nice, thank you DJP!